# Is there any way to block renaming of a Particular Folder by any user in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, directory

**How to block the renaming of a Particular Folder by Ubuntu Users ?**

Comment: You need to change the permission of the parent folder of that folder.

Comment: This question is vague. An example of the problem would provide you more useful answers. Is the renaming malicious? Is it a system folder (like /proc)?  Is it a temporary directory Is it shared using NFS or Samba of FTP?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ownership and permissions of the **parent directory** (in particular the `write` flag) only to the user/group which shall be able to change it.

Renaming in the end means writing to the folder which contains the file/folder.

#### Step 1 - ownership

```
sudo chown <USERNAME>:<GROUPNAME> </path/to/parent_folder>
```

- This makes the file or folder be owned by the user `<USER>` (for blocking all normal users from the change this could be e.g. `root`).
- The `:<GROUPNAME>` is optional and sets the group to  for that file or folder.

If you don't need a special group I'ld recommend use the 's group.
If you want multible users to be able to change, add them all to a new usergroup and set the ownership e.g. to

```
sudo chown root:<GROUPNAME> </path/to/parent_folder>
```

---

To verify it is setup as it should run

```
ls -la </path/to/parent_folder>
```

- This shows you the a list of contained files and the very first entry `.` the folder itself with information about ownership and permissions.

Output could look like

```
drwxrwxr-x   1 root root     0 Dec  4 16:59 .
```

#### Step 2 - permissions

followed by

```
sudo chmod u+w </path/to/parent_folder>
sudo chmod g+w </path/to/parent_folder>
sudo chmod o+w </path/to/parent_folder>
```

This makes

- `u+r` the owner(user) is allowed to write
- `g+r` the group is allowed to write (this is optional and in some cases not wanted -> than change it to `g-r`)
- `o-r` other users are not allowed to write

---

In some cases you might also want the `-R` option for all commands to set the ownership and permissions recursively also on the content of a folder.

**Note**:
Anyway there is no way to prevent that `root` changes anything in your system. So other users could still change using `sudo`.

Comment: For renaming something, permissions on *it* don't matter. Permissions on the parent folder matter.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right I clearified that